# Write a "partial" XAML TypeConverter that can convert to/from only a specific sub-type in a hierarchy

Tags: xaml, .net-4.0, partial, typeconverter, subtype

Given a base class `Color` with at least two sub-types, `RgbColor` and `CmykColor`:

```cs
abstract partial class Color { }

sealed class RgbColor : Color
{
    public byte R { get; set; }
    public byte G { get; set; }
    public byte B { get; set; }
}

sealed class CmykColor : Color
{
    public byte C { get; set; }
    public byte M { get; set; }
    public byte Y { get; set; }
    public byte K { get; set; }
}
```

and some type that I am going to (de-) serialize to/from XAML with .NET 4's `System.Xaml.XamlServices`:

```cs
class Something
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to be able to abbreviate just RGB colors on the XAML side like this:

```
<Something Color="#010203" />
```

instead of having to type everything out:

```
<Something>
  <Something.Color>
    <RgbColor R="1" G="2" B="3" />
  </Something.Color>
</Something>
```

This could be easily done with a `TypeConverter`. (Find my current implementation at the end of this question.) The problem is that I don't need, nor want, a special abbreviation syntax for other sub-types of `Color`, such as `CmykColor`.

**How can I write a `TypeConverter` for `Color` that works only for one of its sub-types, `RgbColor`?**

(I have already tried to write a `TypeConverter` specifically for `RgbColor` instead of for `Color`, but the XAML serializer doesn't appear to use it when it encounters a `Color` property.)

---

```cs
// using System;
// using System.ComponentModel;
// using System.Globalization;

[TypeConverter(typeof(ColorConverter))]
partial class Color { }

sealed class ColorConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        return destinationType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        // omitted for brevity's sake
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        Debug.Assert(value is Color);
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            if (value is RgbColor)
            {
                var color = (RgbColor)value;
                return string.Format("#{0:x2}{1:x2}{2:x2}", color.R, color.G, color.B);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(); // ? 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a different type of converter that can be used for just that: [`ValueSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.valueserializer(v=vs.110).aspx). Value serializers differ from type converters in two key ways:

- They can only convert to/from strings. (Other types aren't relevant for XAML, anyway.)
- They receive the object to be converted already in the `CanConvert...` stage. (That is the important bit.)

The main problem I've had with value serializers is having them invoked by `XamlServices`.

Here's my solution:

First, you must apply not only a value serializer, but also a type converter to the base class:

```cs
// both types of converters must be applied!
[TypeConverter(typeof(ColorConverter))]
[ValueSerializer(typeof(ColorValueSerializer))]
partial class Color { }
```

Without the type converter attribute, the value serializer will never get invoked!

Next, the type converter must be written so that it only converts from strings ([what MSDN calls "the load path"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621339(v=vs.110).aspx#value_serializers)):

```cs
sealed class ColorConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(..., Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(...);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(..., Type destinationType)
    {
        return destinationType != typeof(string) && base.CanConvertTo(...);
        // the above != is not a typo! We must not let
        // the type converter do the conversion to string.
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(...)
    {
        // parse a #rrggbb string and return the corresponding RgbColor
    }
}
```

Finally, let the value serializer deal with conversions to string ([the "save path"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621339(v=vs.110).aspx#value_serializers)):

```cs
sealed class ColorValueSerializer : ValueSerializer
{
    public override bool CanConvertToString(object value, ...)
    {
        return value is RgbColor;
    }

    public override string ConvertToString(object value, ...)
    {
        // convert RgbColor into "#{r}{g}{b}" string
    }
}
```